# Data segmentation. Excel won't let me insert slicers

Tags: excel

For no apparent reason, after inserting slicers successfully, Excel won't let me insert slicers.
I am using it in tables (ListObjects).

At the same time I also can't uncheck the "Disable resizing and moving" box for slicers I already have created.

Can anyone tell me what is causing it and how to fix it?

Thanks.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Everything works again as soon as I have blocked the macros. Somehow the macros in the project were interfering with the data segmentation, I don't know exactly which macros in particular. So the solution is to block macros, insert slicers, and then re-enable macros.

It's a relief. I hope someone else finds it useful.

All the best.